# Dynamically generate textbox when user enters something

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Initially i have one textbox/selectbox when user enters something or selects something generate another textbox/selectbox and also i can set limit how many textbox/selectbox can be generated.

please advice me how can i achieve this

Comment: ok and how i can check user entered anything or not??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery `append()` method to create html dynamically.

```js
$("#ddlOptions").on("change", function(e) {

  var len = $('.txtInput').length;
  if (len == 0) {
    $('.container').append('<br> <input type="text" id=txtTextBox_' + len + ' class="txtInput" /> <br>');
  }
});

$(document).on("change", '.txtInput', function() {
  var len = $('.txtInput').length;
  
  if ($(this).val() != "") {
    $('.container').append('<br> <input type="text" id=txtTextBox_' + len + ' class="txtInput" /> <br>');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <select id="ddlOptions">
    <option>option 1</option>
    <option>option 2</option>
    <option>option 3</option>
    <option>option 4</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: i want to add one by one if first textbox filled generate another if that filled generate another and so on..

Comment: @websmentor.com Please check the snippet. code updated and let me know if you face any issues. :)

Comment: when user enters something in textbox generate selectbox ....how to do that..plz suggest somthing..

Comment: @websmentor.com You can use the same way like you created a textbox, example : `$('.container').append('<br> <select id="mySelect_' + len + ' class="ddlOptions"> <option>option 1</option> <option>option 2 </option></select> <br>');` . Let me know If you need any assistance :)

Comment: hi @Arun i need your help right now for for textbox it is working fine but in case of dropdown every time it is generating multiple dropdowns when user selects another dropdown . but requirement- on change generate only one dropdown and user can change their dropdown selection also no need to generate on every onchange..

Comment: Can you please provide a jsfiddle of your code ?. Your requirement is not clear for me, Tell me what is your requirement.

Comment: here is my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/b592o0yf/1/ it is not working your can save my code in html file first you enter name after that age now suppose you have selected your age wrong you want to change but every time it is generating new field

Comment: @websmentor.com You can use jQuery `one` instead of `on` Which will fire event only once. [jQuery one](http://api.jquery.com/one/ "jQuery one") Check this FIDDLE : https://jsfiddle.net/b592o0yf/2/ . Hope this will help you :)

Comment: Thank You man correct..I am sorry it getting to lengthy but one more help i want to collect all the entered info in form how can i do that  thank you in advance..

Comment: @websmentor.com Use `$('form').serializeArray()`, which returns an array Or you can use Use `$('form').serialize()`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var counter=0;
function generate(){
  var newTxt='<input type="text">';
  var newSel='<select><option value="">--select--</option></select>';
  var txtlimit=document.getElementById('txtlimit');
  var div=document.getElementById('newCtrls');
  var totalElem=div.getElementsByTagName('input').length;
  
  if(!isNaN(txtlimit.value) && txtlimit.value!=''){  
    if(parseInt(txtlimit.value)>counter && 
      parseInt(txtlimit.value)>totalElem){
      div.innerHTML += newTxt + newSel+'<br>';
      counter++;
     }
  }else{
    div.innerHTML +=newTxt + newSel+'<br>';
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txtlimit" placeholder="Enter Limit"><br>
<input type="text" onkeyup="generate();">
<select onchange="generate();">
  <option value="Item1">--select--</option>
  <option value="Item1">Item1</option>
  <option value="Item2">Item2</option>
  <option value="Item3">Item3</option>
</select><br>
<div id="newCtrls">
  <h3>Dynamic Controls Here</h3>
</div>
```